# Need help identifying the formula for the sequence $ \frac{x^5}{5} ,\frac{x^9}{45} ,\frac{x^{13}}{585},...$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence that I am trying to identify the formula for is:
$$ \frac{x^5}{5} ,\frac{x^9}{45} ,\frac{x^{13}}{585},...$$
which can also be written as:
$$ \frac{x^5}{5} ,\frac{x^9}{(5\cdot9)} ,\frac{x^{13}}{(5\cdot9\cdot13)},...$$
I'm trying to do this in terms of x and m for m = 1,2,3,... where each m corresponds to each successive member of the sequence. So for example, m = 1 corresponds to $ \frac{x^5}{5}. $
I have the numerator figured out, (I think) with it being $$ x^{4m+1} $$
I cannot however figure out an expression for the denominator. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In terms of multifactorial, the denominators look like $(4m+1)!!!!$.

Comment: The next term should narrow down the candidate list at [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=5%2C45%2C585&language=english&go=Search).

Comment: Thank you both for the helpful info! OEIS seems like it may be a helpful website in the future. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

About the best you can meaningfully do for the denominator is with the quadruple factorial, a relative of the [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial). Essentially:
$$\begin{align*}
n! &:= n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(2)(1) \\
n!! &:= n(n-2)(n-4)\cdots (2 \text{ or } 1) \\
n!!! &:= n(n-3)(n-6)\cdots (3 \text{ or } 2 \text{ or } 1) \\
n!!!! &:= n(n-4)(n-8)\cdots (4 \text{ or } 3 \text{ or } 2 \text{ or } 1)
\end{align*}$$
Hence I would express your denominator as $(4m+1)!!!!$.

---

Curiously, Wikipedia states that there is [an extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial#Generalizations) of $z!!!!$ that may be useful in this narrow case. Namely,

$$z!!!! = 4^{(z-1)/4} \frac{ \Gamma \left( \frac z 4 + 1 \right)}{  \Gamma \left( \frac 5 4 \right)}$$

when $z \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, which happens to be true for $z=4m+1$. (Or rather, "true" in the sense of being consistent with the definition I gave at the outset.)

This has the more general statement of

$$z!_{(\alpha)} = \alpha^{(z-1)/\alpha} \frac{ \Gamma \left( \frac z \alpha + 1 \right)}{  \Gamma \left( 1 + \frac 1 \alpha \right)}$$

where $\alpha$ is a positive integer indicating the number of factorials used: $\alpha=2$ for the double factorial, $\alpha=3$ for the triple factorial, and so on.

(Here, $\Gamma(z)$ is the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), the usual extension of the ordinary factorial to most complex numbers.)

Comment: I do not know if you are a teacher. If you are, I are sure that you are a good one. Cheers

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed and thoughtful answer. I believe that (4m+1)!!!! was the answer that I needed. I had never heard of multifactorials before today, so I'm glad I asked for help!

Answer (score 1):

$5,9,13,...$ is an arithmetic progression with first term $5$ and common difference $4$. So your denominator in the $n$-th term is the product the first $n$ numbers of the form $4k+1$. You can estimate this in terms of the Gamma function as

$$
\prod_{k = 1}^n (4k+1) = 4^n \left(1+\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(2+\frac{1}{4}\right)\cdots \left(n+\frac{1}{4}\right) 
=  \frac{4^n\Gamma(n + 5/4)}{\Gamma(5/4)} 
= \frac{4^{n-1}\Gamma(n + 5/4)}{\Gamma(1/4)}
$$